# Using the Executor interface instead of explicitly creating threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've read that using the `Executor` interface is a better programming practice than explicitly creating your own threads. In my opinion, it is a lot easier to create my own threads and initialize them in the argument of the `Thread` constructor. What are the advantages of using `Executor` rather than creating the threads the way I've been doing so so far?

Comment: Just interested (if you don't mind) -- have even tried to use google before asking?

Comment: I looked for it in google but only large tutorials appeared. sorry for waisting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating threads is costly operation and thus it is better to return Thread to the thread pool. This is especially needed in servers where for each client request a thread is assigned.

Having hundreds of request per second with re-creating the Thread each time it is needed would influence performance much.

So in cases where little threads will be needed, you can go with creating them without Executor. If your application will likely create many threads, make use of Executor.

Answer (score 1):

With an explicit `Thread` object that's all you get: a thread that runs in parallel. With an `ExecutorService` you get:

- a pool of threads that get recycled between task executions.
- a thread-safe blocking task queue that the threads check for new tasks automatically.
- implicit load-balancing.
- implicit efficiency, since thread creation overheads are avoided.

The `ExecutorService` allows for easy implementation of the producer-consumer paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantage is threads will be used from pool instead of creating everytime.

As per oracle [concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)

> Executors define a high-level API for launching and managing threads. Executor implementations provided by java.util.concurrent provide thread pool management suitable for large-scale applications